# Combining Datasets with Different Features

Tags: machine-learning, dataset

I have multiple datasets, with slightly differing features. What tools can I use to make this a homogeneous dataset?

Dataset1:

```
featureA,featureB,featureC
1,7,3
4,8,4
```

Dataset2:

```
featureA,featureC,featureD,featureE
3,4,5,6
9,8,4,6
```

**Homogeneous Dataset**

```
featureA,featureB,featureC,featureD,featureE
1,7,3,,
4,8,4,,
3,,4,5,6
9,,8,4,6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [R](http://www.r-project.org/) to do that.

[The smartbind function](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/gtools/docs/smartbind) is the perfect way to combine datsets in the way you are asking for:

```
library(gtools)

d1<-as.data.frame(rbind(c(1,7,3),c(4,8,4))))
names(d1)<-c("featureA","featureB","featureC")

d2<-as.data.frame(rbind(c(3,4,5,6),c(9,8,4,6)))
names(d2)<-c("featureA","featureC","featureD","featureE")

d3<-smartbind(d1,d2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Python to do this. If you're familiar using [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) data frames:

```
import pandas as pd

d1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,4], 'B':[7,8], 'C':[3,4]})
d2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[3,4], 'C':[4,8], 'D':[5,4], 'E':[6,6]})

d1.append(d2)
```

This will output what you're looking for, except the empty cells would have NaNs (not a number) in them.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't decided if I'm going to do the larger project with R, Python or both so this is helpful

Comment: I was thinking you were asking how to actually reconcile the inhomogeneity (e.g. fill in the missing values) rather than how to concatenate dataframes with missing values, but it looks like you just needed the append and/or smartbind methods?